# about using "ing" after to

Tags: infinitives

is that correct to say "in order to optimum tracking the route"? I mean when we have another word between "to" and "verb", could we use the infinitive form of the verb (verb+ing)?

Comment: You can use "to+ing" when *to* is a preposition. "Guide to learning English" for example.

Answer (score 1):

No, it would not be correct to use a verb ending with with "ing" in this context. Infinitives do not actually end in "ing", I believe you are thinking of a gerund. An infinitive is the basic form of a verb, such as "to see" or "to walk". So yes, using an infinitive here is fine!

However, you should change the order of the words a bit. An example sentence would be "... in order to provide optimum route tracking."